# Умеет ли С++ работать с HTTP? Ищу библиотеку для telegram бота

Tags: c++, http, telegram-bot, поиск-библиотек

Хочу написать telegram бота на С++, но не знаю подходящей библиотеки. 
Какая есть библиотека для ботов на С++ (с поддержкой HTTP)?

Comment: Зачем пихать плюсы? Используй питон он легковесный и у него достаточно хорошо реализованный telegram api. Либа называеться telebot.

Comment: С такие вещи гораздо проще реализовать, используя Python. Использовать c++ для таких нужд, по мне так плохая идея

Comment: Для винды `wininet.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html), а если точнее - Asio.

Comment: А если ещё точнее, то [Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

Библиотека [tgbot-cpp](https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp) предназначена для создания telegram ботов.
Пример echo бота с использованием данной библиотеки:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgbot/tgbot.h>

int main() {
    TgBot::Bot bot("PLACE YOUR TOKEN HERE");
    bot.getEvents().onCommand("start", [&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message) {
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "Hi!");
    });
    bot.getEvents().onAnyMessage([&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message) {
        printf("User wrote %s\n", message->text.c_str());
        if (StringTools::startsWith(message->text, "/start")) {
            return;
        }
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "Your message is: " + message->text);
    });
    try {
        printf("Bot username: %s\n", bot.getApi().getMe()->username.c_str());
        TgBot::TgLongPoll longPoll(bot);
        while (true) {
            printf("Long poll started\n");
            longPoll.start();
        }
    } catch (TgBot::TgException& e) {
        printf("error: %s\n", e.what());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Также в этой статье описан пример создания бота на Си

https://habr.com/post/325846/

Comment: А как его по винду собрать?